# Copy and Pasting broken on QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis

With the latest update, is anyone else experiencing issues with copying features from one layer to another, or copying features within attribute tables. I am noticing that the keyboard shortcuts for copy and pasting features seem to be causing issues for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since QGIS 3.14, you need to left click on the map canvas( with selected features) and then do the CTRL+C (copy).

The scope of the ctrl+c has been limited to avoid interference with panels.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I do feel the previous behaviour was working well enough and its unfortunate that this change was pushed through. I am sure there were valid reasons though.